# Matrix of Matrixes

Tags: matlab, matrix

Is there a simpler way to create a matrix of matrixes:

A first matrix (9 x 32) that contain value (through a loop) for each item.  I'll have 8 item, so 8 matrix of (9 x 32).  I'll have also 2 condition so 2 * 8 of matrix of (9 x 32).

What is the simplest way to create it?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I'm using matlab, thanks

Comment: To all readers: **DO NOT use `repmat` to initialize a matrix of zeros.**  The accepted answer is way off base. *Please*, use `zeros` or automatic initialization as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26665348/2778484).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html) you can use various techniques to create each matrix. If you have a specific matrix you need to copy you can use the `repmat(M, v, h)` function to repeatedly create it.  Otherwise to create a multidimensional array you can do:

```
B = repmat(0, [r c 8 2])
```

That should give you the matrices you need as a 4 dimensional array, where r is the number of rows, c the columns, 8 the number of repetitions, and 2 conditions. Hopefully that helps you

Comment: Surely `zeros(r,c,8,2)` is easier than `repmat`-ing 0!?

Comment: Might be but I just took an example I saw in the docs.  I'm no matlab expert just trying to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
A = zeros(m,n,8,2)
```

or

```
A(m,n,8,2) = 0;
```